# Using newer OpenGL with MinGW

Tags: windows, opengl, mingw

I'm attempting to compile code that links against OpenGL. It was originally developed for Linux, so for Windows (7) I'm compiling with MinGW.

MinGW includes OpenGL headers and libraries that wrap around the Windows libraries (`opengl32.dll` and `glu32.dll`), however the code contains calls to newer OpenGL features, and fails on compilation. Replacing MinGW's headers (an old version of Mesa3d's headers, supporting OpenGL 1.1) with latest Mesa3d found some success. It will compile, but linking fails as the libraries still lack the symbols (pointing the compiler to Windows OpenGL libraries directly made no difference). I've confirmed the graphics hardware (Nvidia 560M) supports the latest OpenGL standards (indeed, it works on Linux on the same machine).

I've attempted installing Nvidia's SDK, but they only include Direct3d in the latest version (not an option), and no longer offer older versions (which did have OpenGL support) for download.

Am I going about this the right way, and do indeed need Nvidia's SDK, or is there something else I should be doing to link against the proper library?

Edit: The specifically missing functions being linked to are `glBufferData`, `glMapBuffer`, `glUnmapBuffer`, `glBindBuffer`, `glGenBuffer`, and `glDeleteBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an OpenGL loading library, which you should use on both Linux and Windows. This will ensure that you get all of the functions you need for your platforms of interest.

[There are several you can choose from](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library), each with their strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid modifying the original code as much as possible, but from what I'm reading it's becoming clear that I have a core misunderstanding with OpenGL. Despite the name, is it not, in practice, a set of headers you include and libraries you link against?

Comment: Certainly not just that, that's why I was asking in practice.